# get tfidf disribution for new instance in weka

Tags: java, weka, tf-idf

i use `weka` for text classification .i create an Instances object using `TextdirectoryLoader` ,using `StringToWordVector` to create a dataset in `TFIDF` weighting format.then i used `SVM` to classifiy my new instances.now i want to add new feature to dataset Artificially myself and give arbitrary weight  to these attribute in training data.so i i did it and build my classifier.now i want to classify new instance with this model.but i need to first calculate `TFIDF` weighting for this instance by hand .i can not use used filter , because i changed the feature vector so used filter's setting get changed .how can i calculate this new instance by hand ?